# How to resolve these compiler warnings?

Tags: c++, for-loop, compiler-warnings, ternary-operator

For the following code:

```
auto count = 0;
auto iter = container.begin()

for(; count < numNodes; ++iter, ++count){//do something}
```

I get the following warning from g++:

> warning: variables 'count' and 'numNodes' used in loop condition not
>   modified in loop body [-Wfor-loop-analysis] for(; count < numNodes;
>   ++iter, ++count){

It is evident that count is modified as part of the loop increment, whereas numNodes is a constant used in the loop test condition.

Elsewhere, for the following print statement to std::cout:

```
cout << "Is Root?" << pN->isRoot() ? "Yes" : "No" ;
```

where the invocation pN->isRoot() returns a boolean, and I have attempted to combine this fact into a suitable ternary operator, I get the following warning from g++:

> warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value] cout << "Is Root?"
>   << pN->isRoot() ? "Yes" : "No";

Any suggestions to overcome these warnings would be appreciated.

TIA

Vinod

Follow-up, posting the code for the template function definition as a MWE:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> 
tree<T1,T2>::tree(int numNodes, T2& rData)
{
  auto iter = hierarchy.begin();
  auto count = 0;
  for(; count < numNodes; ++iter, ++count)
  {
    *iter = make_unique<node<T1>>(rData[count]);
  }
  auto iter = hierarchy.begin();
  lnkNodes(iter);
}
```

Comment: For the second, add brackets to clarify the order of evaluation, which might actually be the problem in your code (does it perform as expected, btw?).

Comment: Can you turn it to a [mcve]? Hard to say what may be wrong with such a small peephole into your code.

Comment: How come you're not using the iterator to determine if the for loop should end? (using `container.end()`)

Comment: The second question: check precedence of `<<` and `?:`.

Comment: Can't reproduce the first problem, please provide a [mcve] and specify your compiler version and compilation flags.

Comment: I shall edit my original question to post the code for the complete template function definition, wherein I get the first error.

Comment: The posted example doesn't compile. Make sure code you post can be copied, pasted and compiled, with no actions in between.